# href anchor element, second page

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, hyperlink, anchor-scroll

I have a navigation bar whose links go to the anchors on the home page.

I wished on another page that these links also arrive on the home page and towards the anchors.

Here is my code.

Thanking you,

```html
<li role="presentation" class="nav-item active">
   <a href="#" class="nav-link scroll" data-goto="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
</li>
```

...

```html
<section id="portfolio">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your question:** How can I link to my portfolio on my homepage from another page.

**My answer:** Link using `<a href="index.html#portfolio">Go to my portfolio on my homepage</a>` on/from the other page

**Other discussion:**

Why not

```
 <li role="presentation" class="nav-item active">
   <a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link scroll">Portfolio</a>
 </li>
```

I assume you have some kind of scroller. If you do, ***you need to reuse it with the hash of the page you are on***.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.

Yes indeed, I have a scroll in JS.

I forgot to say that I was working locally with MAMP,
 
I would like to keep "data-goto =" "

For the moment I can't do it ^^

Thank you

Comment: You can keep it but then call the function on page load if there is a hash in the URL that matches an ID on the page

Comment: that is to say ?

this does not work : 
<li role="presentation" class="nav-item active"><a href="/index.php/#" class="nav-link scroll" data-goto="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>

Comment: That is not what I posted. What is  `href="/index.php/#"`  supposed to do

Comment: I agree, that's not what you posted, in your example are you using data-goto ?

Comment: Your question: How can L link to my portfolio on my homepage from another page.
My answer: Link using `<a href="index.html#portfolio">Go to my portfolio on my homepage</a>` on/from the other page

Comment: Sorry,
At the moment it only works on the home page.

<a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link scroll" data-goto="portfolio">Portfolio</a>

Comment: What part of `I wished on another page that these links also arrive on the home page and towards the anchors.` do I not understand?

Comment: it works if I write the link like this:

<a href="../site21/#portfolio" class="nav-link scroll" data-goto="portfolio">Portfolio</a>

Comment: Thank you so much,

It's not top top
because I have in the url / # ...